# How can i use Telerik Asp.net ajax RadEditor in MVC5 Razor Project

Tags: telerik, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I have **MVC5** Project and now i want to use **Telerik Asp.net ajax RadEditor**. We have doubled checked those control is only for aspx projects.

but.I got one project in there used like one mvc project and in there call one .aspx partial page then RadEditor is displaying nice but not working document management functionality

Download this project from [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/can-we-use-ribbion-asp-net-ajax-control-in-asp-net-mvc). and just replace my RadEditor code.

Can i use in MVC5? if yes then give me solution if possible.

Awaiting for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, and the documentation says so as well: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/mvc-integration-with-telerik-ui-for-aspnet-ajax.html

Perhaps a WebForms page in the project, or an iframe that points to a WebForms page with the editor will serve your need.

The problem is that MVC does not offer the lifecycle WebForms controls need, and the document manager functionality uses a lot of server code. The ASP.NET MVC plaform is simply too different.